# Deleting specific elements in a list when they come together

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose I have the following list

```
l={{"x","b","c"},{"y","a","d"},{"x","b","y"},{"x","y","c"}}
```

I want to go through the list l and delete elements whenever `"x"` and `"y"` appear both in a single sublist such that I get:

```
{{"x","b","c"},{"y","a","d"}}
```

Order does not matter, as long as `"x"` and `"y"` both exist.

Comment: Thanks for accepting an answer, but I think you were too hasty doing that. While *accepting* is one of the [things to do after your question is answered](https://wolfr.am/v57DB3p4), we recommend that users should **test answers before [voting](https://wolfr.am/v57ItzJq)** and **wait 24 hours before [accepting](https://wolfr.am/v57LwTXD)** the best one. That allows people in all timezones to answer your question and an opportunity for other users to point alternatives, caveats or limitations of the available answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like the following?

```
l = {{"x", "b", "c"}, {"y", "a", "d"}, {"x", "b", "y"}, {"x", "y", "c"}};
DeleteCases[l, {OrderlessPatternSequence["x", "y", ___]}]

(* Out: {{“x”, “b”, “c”}, {“y”, “a”, “d”}} *)
```

Comment: Thank you for this.

Comment: @William you are very welcome.

Comment: @William Upvoting and accepting suffices. Comments are only for improvement suggestions, not "private messaging".

Answer (score 6):

```
DeleteCases[l, _?(ContainsAll[{"x", "y"}])]
```

> {{"x", "b", "c"}, {"y", "a", "d"}}

Answer (score 5):

A different solution using [`SubsetQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SubsetQ.html) and [`Select`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html). I also prefer ti limit the scope of the variable definitions using [`With`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/With.html) or [`Module`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Module.html).

```
With[
 {
  l = {{"x", "b", "c"}, {"y", "a", "d"}, {"x", "b", "y"}, {"x", "y", "c"}}
  },
 Select[l, Not[SubsetQ[#, {"x", "y"}]] &]
 ]
```

Comment: It's not documented, but `SubsetQ` supports an operator form, so you could eliminate the pure function and instead do `Select[l, Not @* SubsetQ[{"x", "y"}]]`

Comment: @CarlWoll Nice tip.  I really wish `! SubsetQ[{"x", "y"}]` would work however.

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {{"x", "b", "c"}, {"y", "a", "d"}, {"x", "b", "y"}, {"x", "y", "c"}};
```

Using `SequenceSplit` (new in 11.3)

```
First @ SequenceSplit[list, {_?(ContainsAll[{"x", "y"}])}]
```

{{"x", "b", "c"}, {"y", "a", "d"}}

Answer (score 0):

```
l = {{"x", "b", "c"}, {"y", "a", "d"}, {"x", "b", "y"}, {"x", "y", "c"}};
```

---

Using `Pick`:

```
Pick[#, Intersection[#1, #2] =!= #2 & @@@ Tuples[{#, Inactive@{"x", "y"}}]] &@l

(*{{"x", "b", "c"}, {"y", "a", "d"}}*)
```